# Django BaseManager and DefaultManager clarification

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am using Django 3.2.  I am reading a section on Custom managers, and came across this text in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/managers/):

> By default, Django uses an instance of the Model._base_manager manager
> class when accessing related objects (i.e. choice.question), not the
> _default_manager on the related object. This is because Django needs to be able to retrieve the related object, even if it would otherwise
> be filtered out (and hence be inaccessible) by the default manager.
>
> If the normal base manager class (django.db.models.Manager) isn’t
> appropriate for your circumstances, you can tell Django which class to
> use by setting Meta.base_manager_name.
>
> Base managers aren’t used when querying on related models, or when
> accessing a one-to-many or many-to-many relationship. For example, if
> the Question model from the tutorial had a deleted field and a base
> manager that filters out instances with deleted=True, a queryset like
> Choice.objects.filter(question__name__startswith='What') would include
> choices related to deleted questions.

The section text seems a bit convoluted. Is it possible to explain what is being said in the above text, by using the models below?

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    deleted = models.Boolean(default=False)
    # ...

class FooBar(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='foos')
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(default=now, db_index=True)
    end_date = models.DatetTimeField(default=now+timeddelta(days=200), db_index=True)
    # ...
```

Comment: I did some experimenting: https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/base-manager-docs-are-confusing/15830/4